# CKEditor onReady is not a function angular2

Tags: angular, configuration, ckeditor

I have configured according the documentation https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor. but it's giving me an error that onReady is not a function.

the html code i'm using is

```
<ckeditor
  [(ngModel)]="ckeditorContent"
  [config]="config"
  (change)="onChange($event)"
  (ready)="onReady($event)"
  (focus)="onFocus($event)"
  (blur)="onBlur($event)"
  debounce="1000"
  >
</ckeditor>
```

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: no i didn't find a fix for this so i used another editor instead

Comment: I have the same issue, anyone?